# Stop notices from undefined indexes in arrays

Tags: php, arrays

PHP returns a "notice" whenever an array index is undefined.

How can I turn these notices off? Or even better, correctly code for them?

Example:

```
$job_db_ready = array(
    "email" => $this->profile['email'],
    "company" => $job['company']['name'],
    "position" => $job['title'],
    "industry" => $job['company']['industry'],
    "start_date_month" => $job['startDate']['month'],
    "start_date_year" => $job['startDate']['year'],
    "end_date_month" => $job['endDate']['month'], // Sometimes endDate undefined
    "end_date_year" => $job['endDate']['year'],  // Sometimes endDate undefined
    "is_current" => $job['isCurrent']
);
```

This array will return

```
Severity: Notice
Message:  Undefined index: endDate
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Ever considered properly defining your array keys/indexes before working with them?

Answer (score 1):

1) **Better Coding Style** :Check if your variable is defined first with `isset` before assigning it to a key in the array. Like this

```
isset($job['endDate']['month']) // Do something about it
```

2) **Turning of error**: Use this in your script before doing something weird

```
error_reporting(0);
```

**1 is recommended 2 is NOT**

Answer (score 1):

Turning of notices is a bad practice as they are there to alert you to possible errors on your part. Instead, check to see if they are defined and if they aren't assign a default value (including null or an empty string):

```
"end_date_month" => (isset($job['endDate']['month']) ? $job['endDate']['month'] : ''), 
"end_date_year"  => (isset($job['endDate']['year'])  ? ($job['endDate']['year'] : ''),
```

Comment: Thanks John, you're 2 for 2 today :P

Answer (score 0):

Put the following at the top of your PHP script:

```
error_reporting( 0 );
```

See [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) on the PHP docs for further information.

Comment: That's a **really** bad practice.

Comment: I never said it was **good** practice, all he asked for was a solution and this is a less messy solution.